# Pinging host from virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, kali-linux

I have Windows 7 running as the host OS.I just installed my copy of Virtual Box and run Kali Linux as the virtual OS.I disconnected my host from the wireless connection at home,and it got connected to the Virtual Box Host Only Network(with IP 192.168.56.1).I could ping the host from the virtual machine(with IP 10.0.2.15),but was unsuccessful to do so vice versa.To solve this problem,I tried to assign the virtual machine a static IP of 192.168.56.8 in the same network as the host OS.But now I was unable to even ping the host from the virtual machine.I tried to change the network type in virtual box from NAT to bridged,then to host only and internal network type but to no avail.I still cannot ping any machine from the other.How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

first turn off the firewall of host machine it may help and set ip_forward=1
For setting ip_forward=1, you have to do
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
or
echo 1 < /proc/net/ipv4/ip_forward